# Strange behavior of MongoDB LINQ provider for fields called "id"

Tags: linq, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Here's a JSON document where Mongo LINQ provider fails:

```
{"results":
     {"text":"@twitterapi  http://tinyurl.com/ctrefg",
     "to_user_id":396524,
     "to_user":"TwitterAPI",
     "from_user":"jkoum",
     "metadata":
     {
      "result_type":"popular",
      "recent_retweets": 109
     },
     "id":1478555574, 
     "from_user_id":1833773,
     "iso_language_code":"nl",
     "source":"<a href=\"http://twitter.com/\">twitter<\/a>",
     "profile_image_url":"http://s3.amazonaws.com/twitter_production/profile_images/118412707/2522215727_a5f07da155_b_normal.jpg",
     "created_at":"Wed, 08 Apr 2009 19:22:10 +0000",
     "since_id":0,
     "max_id":1480307926,
     "refresh_url":"?since_id=1480307926&q=%40twitterapi",
     "results_per_page":15,
     "next_page":"?page=2&max_id=1480307926&q=%40twitterapi",
     "completed_in":0.031704,
     "page":1,
     "query":"%40twitterapi"}
}
```

Note an "id" field. Here are related C# entity definitions:

```
class Twitter
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public Result results { get; set; }
}

private class Result
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public int to_user_id { get; set; }
    public string to_user { get; set; }
    public string from_user { get; set; }
    public Metadata metadata { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int from_user_id { get; set; }
    public string iso_language_code { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
    public string profile_image_url { get; set; }
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public int since_id { get; set; }
    public int max_id { get; set; }
    public string refresh_url { get; set; }
    public int results_per_page { get; set; }
    public string next_page { get; set; }
    public double completed_in { get; set; }
    public int page { get; set; }
    public string query { get; set; }
}

class Metadata
{
    public string result_type { get; set; }
    public int recent_retweets { get; set; }
}
```

If I create a "Twitter" collection and save the document above, then when I query it using Mongo LINQ provider, it throws a FileFormatException exception:
"Element 'id' does not match any field or property of class Mongo.Context.Tests.NativeTests+Result"

However there are two alternative workarounds to fix this problem:

1. Rename Result "id" field, e.g. to "idd" both in JSON doc and the Result class. Then LINQ query works.
2. Keep "id" field but in addition add a field "Id" to the Result class and mark it with attribute [BsonId]. Now the Result class contains both "Id" and "id" fields, but the query works!

I use Mongo API to query the collection, everything works fine, so I guess this must be a bug in a MongoDB LINQ provider. "id" in a nested JSON element should not be a reserved work, should it?

**UPDATE**: Here's the result of a native API query execution:

```
> db.Twitter.find().limit(1);

{ "_id" : ObjectId("50c9d3a4870f4f17e049332b"),
 "results" : { 
    "text" : "@twitterapi  http://tinyurl.com/ctrefg", 
    "to_user_id" : 396524, 
    "to_user" : "TwitterAPI", 
    "from_user" : "jkoum", 
    "metadata" : { "result_type" : "popular", "recent_retweets" : 109 }, 
    "id" : 1478555574, 
    "from_user_id" : 1833773, "
    iso_language_code" : "nl", 
    "source" : "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/\">twitter</a>", 
    "profile_image_url" : "http://s3.amazonaws.com/twitter_production/profile_images/118412707/2522215727_a5f07da155_b_normal.jpg", 
    "created_at" : "Wed, 08 Apr 2009 19:22:10 +0000", 
    "since_id" : 0, 
    "max_id" : 1480307926, 
    "refresh_url" : "?since_id=1480307926&q=%40twitterapi", "results_per_page" : 15,    "next_page" : "?page=2&max_id=1480307926&q=%40twitterapi", 
    "completed_in" : 0.031704, 
    "page" : 1, 
    "query" : "%40twitterapi" 
    } 
}
```

Comment: +1 for workarounds - thanks. Interestingly, it seems the error is only raised if a contained single instance object has an `id` field. A `List` child element with `id` had no problems.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

MongoDB requires that every document stored in the database have a field (at the root level) called "_id".

The C# driver assumes that any field in your class called "Id", "id" or "_id" is meant to be mapped to the special "_id" field. This is a convention, one that can be overridden. The C# driver doesn't know that your Result class isn't meant to be used as the root document of a collection, so it finds your "id" field and maps it to "_id" in the database.

One way you can override this is to change the name of the field in your class (as you discovered). What you can then also do is use the [BsonElement] attribute to map your C# field name (e.g. "idd") to whatever name is actually being used in the database (e.g. "id"). For example:

```
public class Result
{
    [BsonElement("id")]
    public int idd; // matches "id" in the database
    // other fields
}
```

Another alternative is to override the convention that finds the "Id" member of a class to suppress the default behavior of the C# driver for your Result class. You can do this by registering a new ConventionProfile for your Result class. For example:

```
var noIdConventions= new ConventionProfile();
noIdConventions.SetIdMemberConvention(new NamedIdMemberConvention()); // no names
BsonClassMap.RegisterConventions(noIdConventions, t => t == typeof(Result));
```

You must be sure to do this very early in your program, before your Result class gets mapped.

Comment: I've created a JIRA ticket for this issue as it seems like there should be an easy way to override the mapping of id to _id when you don't want that to happen. See: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-648

Comment: thank you for the clarifiction. No I know how it works internally. In the JIRA ticket I liked the alternative with using BsonNoId attribute for nested documents. Easy to grasp and use. If we think about convention over configuration, do you think that mapping can be by default disabled for nested classes, i.e. if a class is defined within another class and the outer class has an Id or [BsonId]-marked field?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your POCO doesn't match your JSON

Your `Twitter` class has an ID and a class called results
Yet, your JSON just has results. That's where the problem lies.

So in reality, you're bypassing the `Twitter` class, and just creating an instance of `Result`

Your JSON should look something like:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("50c9c8f3e0ae76405f7d2b5e"), 
  "results": { 
     "text":"@twitterapi  http://tinyurl.com/ctrefg",
     "to_user_id":396524,
     "to_user":"TwitterAPI",
     "from_user":"jkoum",
     "metadata":
     {
      "result_type":"popular",
      "recent_retweets": 109
     },
     "id":1478555574, 
     "from_user_id":1833773,
     "iso_language_code":"nl",
     "source":"<a href=\"http://twitter.com/\">twitter<\/a>",
     "profile_image_url":"http://s3.amazonaws.com/twitter_production/profile_images/118412707/2522215727_a5f07da155_b_normal.jpg",
     "created_at":"Wed, 08 Apr 2009 19:22:10 +0000",
     "since_id":0,
     "max_id":1480307926,
     "refresh_url":"?since_id=1480307926&q=%40twitterapi",
     "results_per_page":15,
     "next_page":"?page=2&max_id=1480307926&q=%40twitterapi",
     "completed_in":0.031704,
     "page":1,
     "query":"%40twitterapi"}
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Your `results` is actually an embedded document (in the case of your POCO model currently) so you should also mark Result.ID with [BsonId]

Comment: Thanks Alex, I first thought you explained the behavior, but then I looked at the content of the MongoDB. Forget about the original JSON: it was used to insert the data. Now the data are inserted and the document has it's ObjectId. So when I query the collection, the document's Id is properly mapped to Twitter.Id, and there are no more Mongo IDs in the document, so the nested element shouldn't need to map anything.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "so the nested element shouldn't need to map anything" - could you post the verbatim result of (for example)  db.collection.find().limit(1)

Comment: Sure, I've just updated the original post with the result of a native Mongo API call. As you can see, the ObjectId is attached to the outer document, not to the nested "results" element. Moreover I could have multiple nested elements, and none of them will have corresponding IDs.

Comment: This was not the case for my problem; my problem was exactly as mentioned in the selected solution above: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13869920/980423