# MongoDB C# Driver - Ignore fields on binding

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

When using a FindOne() using MongoDB and C#, is there a way to ignore fields not found in the object?

EG, example model.

```
public class UserModel
{
    public ObjectId id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Now we also store a password in the MongoDB collection, but do not want to bind it to out object above. When we do a Get like so,

```
  var query = Query<UserModel>.EQ(e => e.Email, model.Email);
  var entity = usersCollection.FindOne(query);
```

We get the following error

```
Element 'Password' does not match any field or property of class
```

Is there anyway to tell Mongo to ignore fields it cant match with the models?

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Yes. Just decorate your `UserModel` class with the `BsonIgnoreExtraElements` attribute:

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class UserModel
{
    public ObjectId id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

As the name suggests, the driver would ignore any extra fields instead of throwing an exception. More information here - [Ignoring Extra Elements](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/bson/mapping/#ignoring-extra-elements).

Comment: @l3arnon Can this be set globally?

Comment: It can be set globally using a convention, as noted here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-965.  We don't ignore extra elements by default because it means you are losing data, and that isn't safe.

Answer (score 54):

Yet Another possible solution, is to register a convention for this.

This way, we do not have to annotate all classes with **[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]**.

Somewhere when creating the mongo client, setup the following:

```
        var pack = new ConventionPack();
        pack.Add(new IgnoreExtraElementsConvention(true));
        ConventionRegistry.Register("My Solution Conventions", pack, t => true);
```

Comment: Thanks.. that helped me a lot to not decorage all my poco's with the ObjectId. This way i have a clean datacontract without any mongo specific dependencies.

Comment: This solution is also very useful when the models you save on DB are from third party libraries such in this case: 

https://github.com/souzartn/IdentityServer4.Samples.Mongo

Comment: Please also see the comment from screig, you need to do this before create the MongoClient. (I'm not sure but I think in the last few version this was not the case)

Comment: This works perfectly when you have a model with an `Id` property which you do _not_ want serialized to `_id`.

Answer (score 32):

Yes. Another way (instead of editing you model class) is to use `RegisterClassMap` with `SetIgnoreExtraElements`.

In your case just add this code when you initialize your driver:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<UserModel>(cm =>
{
     cm.AutoMap();
     cm.SetIgnoreExtraElements(true);
});
```

You can read more about ignoring extra elements using class mapping here - [Ignoring Extra Elements](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/bson/mapping/#ignoring-extra-elements).

Comment: FYI, this only works if called BEFORE initialising the Mongo client (one day wasted).

Comment: In my ASP.NET Core application I need to restart the application in order for the Class Map to take effect.I first do the mappings, then populate initial data in the DB. If I don't restart I get a deserialization exception from the MongoDb C# Driver. Do you know how can I avoid the restart?

Comment: Note, this doesn't ignore extra properties on nested properties bound to a class